# R improvement of time consuming repeat function

Tags: r, performance, random, repeat

I need to generate random sample (shuffling only values within column), check if it meets condition and store the "good" ones. I need 1000 random samples. With help of other posts I made this code, but it is awfully time consuming. Is there a better solution?

```
ds = matrix(sample(0:1000, 120), ncol=20)

rep <- function(ds) {
    success <- FALSE
  while (!success) {
    x <- apply(ds,2,sample, replace=TRUE)
    success <- all(as.logical(colSums(x) <=  colSums(ds)))
  }
  #compute something based on random matrix that meets condition and return 
  #value
  }
  y=mean(x)
  return(y)
}
replicate(1000, {rep(ds)})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you run this in parallel - column wise?

Comment: I also think that column by column sampling would be a good idea. In the current specification, the chance of `success` is roughly 1 in (2^20)

Comment: I was thinking in that direction but I don't know where to start - if there is a way to put condition inside sample function, or to sample column by column and check for condition, or ...

Comment: Can you write an example how to code it? I am new at this, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the idea I wrote in the comment `suc_samp` return a successful sampling for a vector and `my_rep` apply this successful sampling to each column (`rep` is a base R function so you may want to avoid masking it).

```
suc_samp <- function(x) {
  while(1) {
    x_samp <- sample(x, size = length(x), TRUE)
    if(sum(x_samp) <= sum(x)) break
  }
  return(x_samp)
}

my_rep <- function(ds) {
  x <- apply(ds, 2, suc_samp)
  y <- mean(x)
  return(y)
}

ds <- matrix(sample(0:1000, 120), ncol=20)

replicate(1000, {my_rep(ds)})
```